# Retain ViewModel through orientation change

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, screen-orientation

I have a `LoginActivity`, where `ViewModel` is injected using dagger. `LoginActivity` calls an API through `ViewModel` upon click of a button. Meanwhile, if the screen rotates, it triggers `onDestroy` of `LoginActivity` and there, I dispose that API call. After this, in `onCreate()`, new instance of ViewModel is injected and because of this, my state is lost & I need to tap again in order to make API call.

Here's my LoginActivity:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)

        val loginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<LoginBindings>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
        loginBinding.loginVm = loginViewModel
        loginBinding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        loginViewModel.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Here's my LoginViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(private val validator: Validator,
                     private val resourceProvider: ResourceProvider,
                     private val authenticationDataModel: AuthenticationDataModel) : BaseViewModel() {

    val userName = ObservableField("")
    val password = ObservableField("")
    val userNameError = ObservableField("")
    val passwordError = ObservableField("")

    fun onLoginTapped() {

        // Validations
        if (!validator.isValidUsername(userName.get())) {
            userNameError.set(resourceProvider.getString(R.string.invalid_username_error))
            return
        }

        if (!validator.isValidPassword(password.get())) {
            passwordError.set(resourceProvider.getString(R.string.invalid_password_error))
            return
        }

        val loginRequest = LoginRequest(userName.get(), password.get())
        addToDisposable(authenticationDataModel.loginUser(loginRequest)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe { isApiCallInProgress.set(true) }
                .doOnDispose {
                    LogManager.e("LoginViewModel", "I am disposed, save me!!")
                    isApiCallInProgress.set(false) }
                .subscribe({ user ->
                    isApiCallInProgress.set(false)
                    LogManager.e("LoginViewModel", user.name)
                }, { error ->
                    isApiCallInProgress.set(false)
                    error.printStackTrace()
                }))
    }
}
```

My BaseViewModel:

```
open class BaseViewModel {

    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()
    val isApiCallInProgress = ObservableBoolean(false)

    fun addToDisposable(disposable: Disposable) {
        disposables.add(disposable)
    }
    fun onDestroy() {
        disposables.clear()
    }
}
```

Here's the module which provides the ViewModel:

```
@Module
class AuthenticationModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginViewModel(validator: Validator, resourceProvider: ResourceProvider,
                              authenticationDataModel: AuthenticationDataModel): LoginViewModel {
        return LoginViewModel(validator, resourceProvider, authenticationDataModel)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAuthenticationRepo(): IAuthenticationRepo {
        return AuthRepoApiImpl()
    }

}
```

How can I retain my `ViewModel` through orientation changes. **(Note: I am NOT using `Architecture Components' ViewModel`)**. Should I make my ViewModel `Singleton`? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: What is `loginViewModel.onDestroy()`?

Comment: onDestroy is in `BaseViewModel` to which the `LoginViewModel` extends & `onDestroy()` just clears the `CompositeDisposable` for now.

Comment: Oh i missed the part when  you say you're not using AAC, when you're using AAC you get same instance of your viewmodel each time you request it, so i guess you need to make kind of dagger singleton for your viewmodel to make something similar (or just use AAC instead)

Comment: Yes, that is the way, but I am not sure if it's correct approach or not as I am not sure that if 2 `Activities` requests the same `ViewModel`, AAC provides same instance or different instance `PerActivity`?. If second is the case, using `PerActivity` scope with dagger might work no?

Comment: There is no point of using different viewmodel instance for same activities (even if different instance) and i think AAC using same instance for same activity class is the right way to go